# Excel macro to run for all sheets except one

Tags: excel, vba

The Excel macro below runs on several predetermined sheets and formats them. I'm looking to modify it to have it format all sheets in the workbook except one.

All sheets, regardless of name, should be formatted except for the Lookup sheet.

The code listed below was shortened to show just one sheet, it does the exact same thing for 10 other sheets but I didn't want to put all of it here. Thank you.

```
Sub Formatting()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Sheets("Products").Select
Columns("F:W").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("X1").Select
Selection = "Product #"
Range("X1").Font.Bold = True


With Sheets("Products")
    .Range("X2:X" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row).Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(S2,Lookup!C:D,2,FALSE)),"""",VLOOKUP(S2,Lookup!C:D,2,FALSE))"
    .Range("Z2:Z" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row).Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(S2,Lookup!C:D,2,FALSE)),"""",VLOOKUP(S2,Lookup!C:D,2,FALSE))"
    .Range("AC2:AC" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row).Formula = "=IF(Z2="""","""",E2)"
End With


Range("A1:X50").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Products").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Products").Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("X2:X50"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Products").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:X50")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Columns("X:X").ColumnWidth = 9

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You are far better off using a loop. I am assuming you have this piece of code 11 times, why not write it once and let the code loop through it 11 times? With such 
a loop you can add an `If` statement to determine whether the sheet in the current iteration is the one you want to skip, and do so accordingly https://excelhelphq.com/how-to-loop-through-worksheets-in-a-workbook-in-excel-vba/

Comment: Additionally, using `Select` and `Activate` are functions best to be avoided. Give the following link a read :) https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping through the worksheets is the key:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Formatting()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not ws.Name = "LookUp" Then 'the sheet with the lookup name
            'your formatting code
        End If
    Next ws    

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Damian this makes it much simpler.